# Passing properties file to Oozie Java Action

Tags: java, hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator, camus

I have a Oozie java action workflow set up, which I plan to use an Oozie coordinator to schedule. The java action runs a Camus Job, whose jar and properties config file I have put in the workflow/lib directory. Any ideas on how I would pass the -P argument to this? Currently, I'm doing something like this:

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5" name="camus-wf">
    <start to="camusJob"/>
    <action name="camusJob">
        <java>
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <configuration>
            <property>
                    <name>mapred.job.name</name>
                    <value>camusJob</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                    <value>${queueName}</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <main-class>com.linkedin.camus.etl.kafka.CamusJob</main-class>
    <arg>-P</arg>
    <arg>${camusJobProperties}</arg>
        </java>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="fail"/>
    </action>
    <kill name="fail">
        <message>${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

Where camusJobProperties looks like

```
hdfs://10.0.2.15:8020/coordCamusJob/workflowAppPath/lib/config.properties
```

But the workflow doesn't seem to run (gets stuck on PREP). Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks!

EDIT: After correcting my nameNode URL, I can see that I get the following error:

```
ACTION[0000002-150804091125207-oozie-oozi-W@camusJob] Launcher exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: hdfs://10.0.2.15:8020/user/root/app/workflow/lib/config.properties, expected: file:///
org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMainException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: hdfs://10.0.2.15:8020/user/root/app/workflow/lib/config.properties, expected: file:///
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain.run(JavaMain.java:58)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:39)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain.main(JavaMain.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:450)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: hdfs://10.0.2.15:8020/user/root/app/workflow/lib/config.properties, expected: file:///
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.checkPath(FileSystem.java:645)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.pathToFile(RawLocalFileSystem.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:603)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:821)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:598)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:414)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:766)
    at com.linkedin.camus.etl.kafka.CamusJob.run(CamusJob.java:679)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at com.linkedin.camus.etl.kafka.CamusJob.main(CamusJob.java:646)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain.run(JavaMain.java:55)
    ... 15 more
```

So basically my question is how would I pass the properties file argument when the properties file is located in the HDFS (in particular, in the workflow/lib directory)

Comment: are you sure this is because of the properties arg? what happens if you remove that arg. does it launch the job and throw some error?

Comment: @sonic No, you're correct, it remains stuck on prep even without the argument. So its probably something else. I'll try implementing it differently (perhaps as a map reduce action).

Comment: check your jobtracker and namenode url

Comment: Thanks! It appears my nameNode URL was incorrect, and so now it works, but still gives another error, which does relate to the problem I suspected initially (funny how that works). I get the following error:
"hdfs://10.0.2.15:8020/user/root/app/workflow/lib/config.properties, expected: file:///
org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMainException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: hdfs://10.0.2.15:8020/user/root/app/workflow/lib/config.properties, expected: file:///"

but when I try to pass "/user/root/app/workflow/lib/config.properties" directly it gives a file not found.

Comment: That's because you have not configured your core-site.xml to use hdfs. By default core-site will be having file system configures

Comment: Thanks, is there any way I could do this without configuring core-site.xml? And if not, how would I go about configuring core-site.xml? I currently have fs.defaultFS set as hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020 to true

Comment: It looks like your core-site.xml is correct, the issue might be that in Java action, the config object is not aware of these details. What you have to do is to set the core-site.xml path in your config object

Comment: The Hadoop "Configuration" constructor looks for "core-site.xml" and "hdfs-site.xml" in the CLASSPATH ; if they are not present (or the CLASSPATH does not include `/etc/hadoop/conf/`) then it falls back silently to the LocalFilesystem. And you get excatly that silly error message.

Comment: Afterthought: you may pack custom XML config files in the Workflow, use the alternate constructor `Configuration duh =new Configuration(false) ;` then explicitly ask the Configuration object to source from the custom XML files. But again, if the files are not present or some critical properties are missing, it will fall back silently to LocalFilesystem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part of the question : it might be due to incorrect url of `namenode` or `jobtracker`

For the second part : you have to configure the **core-site.xml**, the property `fs.defaultFS` to `hdfs://host:port/`

Also,
In your Java program set path of core-site.xml in your `config` object

Comment: Thanks!, so I think I already have it setup like that. I have fs.defaultFS set to value hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020, with property true

Comment: I have modified the answer

Comment: Is it possible to do this by adding fsDefault as a property of the Oozie workflow action?

Comment: @JakeChase: were you able to resolve this second issue eventually ?